# jQuery .each then .append bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

// Jade

```
.occ
      h1.occ__reveal Section
      .occ__hidden
        p Content
.occ
      h1.occ__reveal Section
      .occ__hidden
        p Content
.occ
      h1.occ__reveal Section
      .occ__hidden
        p Content
```

// JS

```
$('.occ .occ__hidden').each(function() {
  var button = $('<button>').text('Button');
  $(this).append(button);
})
```

I'm trying to do something similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485925/jquery-help-using-each-and-append-to-add-pictures-to-html?answertab=votes#tab-top), but the output results in multiple 'button' appended on each instance of my .each(). So right now each .occ__hidden element is getting 3 buttons appended. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

It turns out that it was  an issue with the way I was calling my anuglar directive. I was calling the directive as a class and ignorantly named it 'occ'. Since there's 3 instances of the occ class in this example the directive was being executed 3 times, hence the reason why the button element was being appending multiple times. In hindsight I should have shared my code in it's entirety, including the angular portion, but at the time I deemed it unnecessary for simplicity's sake. Sorry for the trouble but I do appreciate the help some of you have offered. Hope this servers as 'gotcha' insight for anyone who encounters this in the future.

Comment: Are you sure that loop is only being run/called once? As shown, the code [works as expected](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/LpvPga)

Comment: Hmmm... I think the jQuery is correct here. I'm currently using and angular directive to call this so it may be an issue with that.

Comment: First thing to do is place breakpoint and see how many times it is called.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYVPzz

Comment: So far as I am concerned, I am only seeing 3 buttons when I tried running your code

Comment: Even if it's not the culprit, `$('<button>')` should be `$('<button/>')`.

Comment: And `$('.occ .occ__hidden').append($('<button/>').text('Button'));
` should do the same job without `.each()`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Really appreciate it. I've added an edit above that explains the reason this was happening. Hopefully I didn't cause too much trouble for you guys.